# get event of child element without triggering same event for parent

Tags: jquery, html

I have parent node and child node. They both have 'click' event listners. Since <a> is child element, I cannot click on it without clicking on parent <div&gt, so always event for parent <div> is triggered. How can I get event for child element <a> without triggering one for parent <div>?
Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2GF4/) and the code:
HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="" id="link"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#link {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#container').on('click', function() {
alert('container');
});
$('#link').on('click', function() {
alert('link');
});
```

Comment: are you sure you posted the right fiddle?

Comment: You are missing `#` sign for ID selector.

Comment: @Sergio, sorry, the fiddle was wrong. I replaced it.

Comment: @undefined, thanks! I've corrected it and now it works as expected! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want propagation of the event to the container, use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) :

```
$('#container').on('click', function() {
    alert('container');
});
$('#link').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('link');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

(if you don't want to trigger the link's default behavior, replace  `e.stopPropagation();` with `return false;`)

Comment: I messed up a little bit with what guys pointed out in comments, so now it works as I expected. But your answer is also very valuable as I imagine this could be the answer to my next question :)

Comment: Why is it that event for '#link' element is triggered first? Is it because it's higher in z-index?

Comment: No, it's because it's downstream in the DOM tree : the child receives the event before the parent.